# React Form Validation Issue

Tags: reactjs, forms, validation

i don't know what is wrong with my code , i check the value with console.log and it gets the value normally but when i submit the form it gets back to undefined , and when i try to check the form with if statement if just send the mail with empty values and sometimes it send undefined

```
const [mails, setMails] = useState({
    userFullName: '',
    userEmail: '',
    userSubject: '',
    userMessage: '',
    mailFail : false,
});

const [mailStatues, setMailStatues] = useState(false);
const [mailLoader, setMailloader] = useState(false);


const { userFullName, userEmail, userSubject, userMessage, mailFail } = mails;

const handleChange = e => {
    setMails({ ...mails, [e.target.name] : e.target.value})
}

function setFail() {
    setMails({ mailFail: true })
    setTimeout(() => {
        setMails({ mailFail: false })
    }, 3000);
 }
const handleEmail = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(userFullName , userEmail, userSubject, userMessage)
    if ( userFullName ) {
        setFail()
    }
 
    else {
    setMailloader(true);
    await axios.post('http://localhost:8000/api/form', { 
        ...mails
    },
        setMails({
            userFullName: '',
            userEmail: '',
            userSubject: '',
            userMessage: '',
        })
        , 
       setMailloader(false)
        ,
       setMailStatues(true)
    )
    }
}
```

here is the form

```
<form onSubmit={handleEmail}>
                            <Input id='inputName' type="text" name="userFullName" label="Name" value={userFullName} change={handleChange} />
                            <Input id='inputEmail' type="email" name="userEmail" label="Email" value={userEmail} change={handleChange}/>
                            <Input id='inputSubject' type="text" name="userSubject" label="Subject" value={userSubject} change={handleChange}/>
                            <TextArea id='inputMessage' type="text" name="userMessage" label="Message" value={userMessage} change={handleChange}/>
                            <BtnAni string="Submit" loading={mailLoader}/>
                    
      </form>
```

Comment: Hello ! could you provide a minimal reproducible example ?

Comment: is there away to run react on stackoverflow ? 

the email with nodemailer is sending normally but my problem only with the validation

Comment: Maybe you could put it in a codesandbox

Comment: here is the link from codesandbox ( i removed the sent function from axios because its not working on codesandbox , this is just the form

https://codesandbox.io/s/headless-cdn-yz0xwq?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change these lines

```
    setMails({ mailFail: true })
    setTimeout(() => {
        setMails({ mailFail: false })
    }, 3000);
```

to

```
    setMails(prev => ({ ...prev, mailFail: true }))
    setTimeout(() => {
        setMails(prev => ({ ...prev, mailFail: false }))
    }, 3000);
```

Comment: Thank you , its working i also set the prev to the handleChange and its working fine ^^